Why is this SE so deserted?
There is an active Bitcoin community at bitcointalks.org and the interest in Bitcoin is increasing at a fast pace.
Isn't there a way to get all the people asking questions on bitcointalks to this medium. Fora are way outdated when it comes to just Q&A and most fora (what about 99.9%?) still require you to make an account... People just wanting their question answered have way less hassle asking them here than on fora.
We should promote this place harder imho :)

We certainly need more questions/day but our other traffic metrics are doing all right. I've noticed that traffic here is pretty "bursty" - every time something new comes out there are a thousand questions at once about it and then... silence... Still, if anyone wants to try to bring bitcointalk users over to the SE site, I won't complain and I'll probably even help ;-)

You could try starting a campaign "This question would work great on the SE!" - seeing what new, interesting questions some up on the forum and redirect them here with some link.

Fun fact: We are now ranked 11th among the (around 50) StackExchange Beta sites based on traffic. That's pretty good.

First, we need to revisit our definition of "deserted" because we're at least meeting SE's baseline criteria in most cases and exceeding it in a few others. We get a pretty fair amount of traffic. If you're interested in increasing our traffic, though, there are plenty of things we can all do to help out:

Generate backlinks to the site - this is as simple as linking to the
site from any sites you control, tweeting the link or otherwise
putting it out there. This doesn't have to be spammy, it can be as
simple as legitimately sharing an interesting link. If you've got a
blog, check into the
StackTack plugin.
Not only does this increase traffic via the links themselves, but
it also helps increase our search engine rankings.
Participate. The best way to sell a site like this
one is the network
effect so your simple
participation helps quite a bit.
A bit more social interaction might take this from being a
place people come for Q&A and make it a place people actually enjoy
spending time. We do have a chat feature and it's grossly
under-utilized on our site. Some of the most successful sites in the
StackExchange network have very active chat rooms. Given that we have
a very active chat room on freenode we should have a built-in
audience, and SE chat is certainly simpler than IRC.
I'm sure there are a thousand other ways we can all contribute and
bring loads of traffic, questions, answers, new users etc. to this
site and make it the best it can possibly be. If anyone has
additional suggestions I'd be happy to incorporate them into this
answer as well!


I was looking at this today. 1/3 of users (25 pages of ~75) have a rep of < 15. This means that they (currently me) cannot even upvote questions. This seems like a problem to me since the community appears to be small still. 
Maybe it's not (and I'm disgruntled because I can't upvote) and other SEs have fought through it, but I would like to see upvoting encouraged for  any sort of participation.
For comparison, SO has 43490 pages of users, 31000 of them are < 15 rep making their ratio 71% of users can't upvote. But pure numbers (~12490 pages) obviously dwarfs this site.

SO is not what you should compare with. Compare with other SE websites in Beta or some that just grew out of Beta.
We're not doing the best job here in our Beta, but really not the worse either.
Check out our area51 page: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30763/bitcoin

I feel like many users come, ask a question, get their answer, and forget about the site. There are lots of people who peruse this SE rearing to answer questions. I've personally learned more from researching to answer questions that I ever could have simply reading BitcoinTalk.

Voting is merely a decentralized regulation measure - the point of SE is helping new (and old) users by giving them quick, clear, and useful answers to their questions. As long as we're doing that, I think we're doing just fine.

A user that has less than 15 rep, has contributed little if anything worthwhile to the SE, yet. Why should he be able to upvote?

But that's part of my point. Because the community is small even if/when people contribute they aren't getting the recognized upvotes to earn the ability to do even basic things. I'm not saying people under 15 rep should be able to upvote, for example, but that the existing community should aggressively promote new member activities. It's a little bit of a chicken/egg problem IMO.

So much ripple spam I stopped watching the rss feeds and answering *coin questions, and I know i m not the only one annoyed by this ripple marketing spam

I am annoyed too.
